# How do I resolve a non-unique HD Identifier problem?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk, mount

I use a HD with a caddy adapter for saving some files. macOS attributes a unique identifier for each external drive connected. But I needed to swap my adapter for the same disk, and now it's not mounting because the identifier is not unique:

> error USBMSC Identifier (non-unique) on console.

In the past, for the same problem, I deleted the drive label/id/something - I don't remember now - on a folder, and my drive would mount normally again when I reconnected it.

**Does anyone know what it is I would have done on the folder to correct these IDs in the past?**

Additional Info:

- The disk is recognized by macOS internet recovery > Disk Utility
- If I put the drive and try to open Disk Utility on currently installed
  macOS, it hangs and doesn't load.
- the disk is showed at command `diskutil list`, but fails to mount using `diskutil mountDisk -t Apple_HFS /dev/disk2 /Volumes/Home`
- If I change the drive name on Internet Recovery and connect it to the macOS installed, it's recognized on the first time, but not on a second.

It's purely a mistake with unique id, and I know it could be resolved by deleting this id or a label, but I wasn't able to find the article with the solution I used previously. I cannot erase the disk because it has some important files, and the drive is working normally. The problem is in the system.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Answer (score 1):

I finally remembered: the disk is mounted on `/dev`, but in this case, not on `/Volumes`. In macOS High Sierra, I:

- excluded both disk and disk partitions from the `/dev` folder using `sudo rm -rf /dev/disk2 && sudo rm -rf /dev/disk2s1`,
- disconnected and reconnected the disk,
- deleted the disk folder mounted at `/Volumes`,
- rebooted the system and it was recognized.

But, it doesn't worked on Mojave.

Using the image on Internet Recovery, I renamed the disk label, which makes the disk being recognized by Mojave. But, as said, it only worked for the first time I connected the disk after renaming.

So, I repeated the renaming, copied my files and formatted it. 
For avoiding futures annoyances, I decided to use NTFS instead of APFS, because the files on this disk could be used as read-only by me on macOS, and, if I need, exchange files using a Windows virtual machine.